# Using a variable with Rows() command in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

I'm writing a for loop that hides or unhides certain blocks of rows depending on a cell input. The problem I'm having is that the Rows() doesn't seem to like my use of i. Any suggestions on what might be wrong here?

```
Rows(i:(i+9)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the range operator (:) like that in VBA. Try something like this

```
Rows(i).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This works on Office 2007

Rows (i & ":" & (i +9)).EntireRow.Hidden = True